# What actor has played the greatest number of unique Marvel or DC characters in movie adaptations?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, dc-extended-universe, casting

I'm fairly certain this hasn't been asked yet based on my search, but apologies if it has. I'm curious what actor has had the most unique roles as a Marvel or DC character in movie adaptations of either universe. Not limited to the MCU or DCEU explicitly, but any film adaptation of the comic books. Off the top of my head I can only think of Chris Evans who has played at least 3: Captain America, The Human Torch and Jensen (from The Losers).

Comment: That's easy...Stan Lee.

Comment: https://www.thewrap.com/ben-affleck-is-batman-and-daredevil-16-more-stars-in-both-marvel-and-dc-movies-photos/

Comment: I think Chris Evans was also a superhero in that movie Push, which I *think was based on a comic*...

Comment: Chris Evans also played Boyfriend No 2 in "Scott Pilgrim vs The World", also based on a comic book.

Comment: @Phlegon_of_Tralles - looks like Push was an original screenplay, so not based on a comic.

Comment: @Paulie_D The popular fan theory, which seems to have been confirmed by his *Guardians of the Galaxy 2* cameo, is that they're all the same character.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assuming you can count Stan Lee out, since he makes a cameo in almost every Marvel movie, then without a doubt it's Chris Evans.

He has played 4 roles derived from comic books:

- Johnny Storm in [*Fantastic Four* (2005)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fantastic_Four_(2005_film)) - Based on the [Marvel Comics book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fantastic_Four)
- Jake Jensen in [*The Losers* (2010)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Losers_(film)) - Based on the [Vertigo comic book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Losers_(Vertigo))
- Lucas lee in [*Scott Pilgrim vs The World* (2010)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scott_Pilgrim_vs._the_World) - Based on the graphic novel [Scott Pilgrim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scott_Pilgrim)
- Steve Rogers in [*Captain America* (2011)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_America:_The_First_Avenger) - Based on the [Marvel Comics book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_America)

and (for the sake of completeness) 1 role in a movie which spawned a comic book:

- Nick Grant in [*Push* (2009)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_(2009_film)) - Spawned the [Wildstorm mini series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_(2009_film)#Comic)

Comment: If Push spawned the Windstorm mini series (which it seems is what happened), then his character in the movie is not based on the comic books, it's vice versa, so I don't think it counts, technically, because the movie would not be an "adaptation."

Comment: True, I just added it for completeness sake, which is why I differentiated it from the rest.  But 4 roles, I believe, is the current one to beat so the answer is still correct until someone tops it.

Comment: No argument here about any of that.

Comment: I would add one more here, Chris Evans voiced Casey Jones in the 2007 TMNT animated film.  I believe he does appear in the comics as well.

Answer (score 7):

## [Lou Ferrigno](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lou_Ferrigno) has **five**…

…if we count different incarnations of the same character as "unique".

### Hulk — Films related to [*The Incredible Hulk*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Incredible_Hulk_(1978_TV_series)) TV series

- *The Incredible Hulk* (1977 pilot film)
- *The Incredible Hulk Returns* (1988 made for TV film)
- *The Trial of the Incredible Hulk* (1989 made for TV film)
- *The Death of the Incredible Hulk* (1990 made for TV film)

[image]

### Security Guard — *[Hulk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hulk_(film))* (2003)

[image]

### Hulk (voice) — *[Hulk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hulk_(film))* (2003)

Note that this film is not in continuity with either the TV series or the Marvel Cinematic Universe, thus this is a different Hulk than than those ones.

[image]

### Security Guard — *[The Incredible Hulk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Incredible_Hulk_(film))* (2008)

While this is the second time Lou Ferrigno has played a security guard in a Marvel movie, the two films are in different continuities and are not implied to be related.

[image]

### Hulk (voice) — Marvel Cinematic Universe films

- *The Incredible Hulk* (2008)
- *The Avengers* (2012)
- *Avengers: Age of Ultron* (2015)
- *Thor: Ragnarok* (2017)

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lou_Ferrigno#Film) notes that Ferrigno was credited for *The Incredible Hulk*, but had uncredited "voice collaborations" for the remaining films.

[image]

Comment: I'd count this as two; Hulk, and Security Guard.  However, even that is a stretch since Security Guard isn't really a MCU character.

Comment: @JohnnyBones That’s fine, you don’t have to upvote the answer. As I put in the preface, this only works if we count the same character in different continuities as unique. Regarding the Security Guard, he does have lines at least, so while he’s not a main character, I do think he’s a character for the purposes of this.

Answer (score 6):

[Donal Logue](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0006610/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cl_t5):

- Gotham (DC, TV) - Harvey Bullock
- Ghost Rider (Marvel, movie) - Mack
- Blade (Marvel, movie) - Quinn

Also, when it comes to TV & Movies, both live action and animated, there are many actors that play multiple characters and voices.  Here are two that come to mind that have played MANY roles and voices.

- [Micheal Rosenbaum](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0742146/)
- [Clancy Brown](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000317/) - Just glancing at his IMDB page, he has over 30 roles in Marvel and DC movies, TV shows, and games.

Comment: Its funny, the list keeps growing and growing.  It almost seems that Marvel and DC just pass actors back and forth.

Answer (score 5):

Stan Lee, he plays a different character in every Marvel movie.  Another thread already has a fairly updated list going https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/37092/actor-with-the-most-comic-book-movie-roles

Comment: at this point in time, this is no longer true.  As of Guardians of the Galaxy Volume 2, he is playing the *same* character.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on whether his role as Commissioner Gordon is up to scratch on Justice League and The Batman, J.K Simmons would have played J Jonah Jameson, a chaotic Marvel character and Jim Gordon, a more calm character.

Answer (score 3):

Besides @johnny's answer I would like to add (as a honorable mention) actor [**Josh Brolin**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josh_Brolin) who played/currently playing 3 comic book characters from both DC and Marvel:

- DC's [Jonah Hex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jonah_Hex) in the movie [Jonah Hex (2010)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jonah_Hex_(film)).
- Marvel's [Thanos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thanos) in [Guardians of the Galaxy (2014)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guardians_of_the_Galaxy_(film)), [Avengers: Age of Ultron (2015)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avengers:_Age_of_Ultron) and the two upcoming [Avengers: Infinity War (2018)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avengers:_Infinity_War) and [Untitled Avengers film (2019)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Untitled_Avengers_film).
- Marvel's [Nathan Summers / Cable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cable_(comics)) in the upcoming [Deadpool 2 (2018)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadpool_2) which is in post-production (shooting is complete).

**Note:** The reason I added Josh Brolin, even though he is beaten by some other actors in the other answers, is because of the importance of his characters and the size of his roles in the aforementioned movies.

Answer (score 3):

Like Chris Evans, Ryan Reynolds is now a veteran with many roles under his belt:

1. [Hannibal King](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Hannibal_King_(Earth-616)%20-%20In%20Blade:%20Trinity) in Blade: Trinity
2. [Green Lantern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_Lantern_(film)) in Green Lantern
3. [Deadpool](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1431045/) in Deadpool 1 & 2
4. [Nick Cruz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R.I.P.D.) in RIPD

Arguably, the character he played in X-Men Origins: Wolverine is a different one from Deadpool as

> Deadpool shoots him in the end credits of *Deadpool 2*

Answer (score 2):

I'd say [Alfre Woodard](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0005569/reference), who played two very different characters in the MCU alone:

**Miriam Spencer**, a grieving mother in "Captain America: Civil War"
[image: Miriam Spencer]

and

**Mariah Dillard**, a shady Harlem councilwoman and a villain in Netflix series "Luke Cage", seen here with her gangster brother 'Cottonmouth'
[image: Mariah Dillard]